# How to write a set of files in OSX sandbox(obecjtive c)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, video, file-permissions, appstore-sandbox

I made a video editing app for OSX called Pompi Video Editor.
I gave the option to save a video as either quicktime movie or MPEG4.
I ask for the user where he wants to save the file using NSSavePanel.
I want to add another export option.
I would like the option to let the user save a set of images where each image is a frame in the video...
For instance MyVideo001.jpg, MyVideo002.jpg, MyVideo003.jpg, MyVideo004.jpg...
(Should be for either jpg or png).
The big issue is that I don't know how to obtain the permissions to write these files, as the app is in sandbox mode since it needs to be on the Apple Store...

Any idea how to be able to let the user save a set of files which are actually his video's frames?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write multiple files using OS X sandbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261842/write-multiple-files-using-os-x-sandbox)

Comment: Ok, I guess I can choose a directory using NSOpenPanel... though I can't do this all in one NSSavePanel? Giving both the option to save as mp4 or mov or select a directory for a set of images?